# Test throw case in RxJava 3

Tags: kotlin, junit, rx-java

I'm trying to test case when my rx chain should throw an exception but facing problem with it. When I'm trying to call `assertError(error)` it says that no error found. Here's example:

```
fun isAvailable(): Single<String> {
    return mapper.getSymbol().map { symbol ->
       if (repository.isAvailable(symbol)) {
          symbol
       } else {
          throw Exception("Symbol is not available")
       }
    }
}
```

In test I mock repository to return false and after do something like:

```
val error = Exception("Symbol is not available")
whenever(mapper.getSymbol()).thenReturn(
    Single.just(
        symbol
    )
)
whenever(repository.isAvailable(symbol)).thenReturn(false)
val test = symbolsRepository.isAvailable().test()

test.await()
    .assertError(error)
```

But when I run test I see
Error not present (latch = 0, values = 0, errors = 1, completions = 0)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Symbol is not available

Comment: I'm not sure, but I'm guessing the issue is that `assertError` compares the exception by using `equals` and your `error` will not be equal to the actual exception thrown.

Answer (score 0):

As @gpunto said, `assertError` does equals check on the `Exception` and those are not implemented by default beyond reference equality in standard Java.

You could use two other overloads of `assertError` to check for both the exception class and its message:

```java
test.awaitDone()
    .assertError(error.getClass())
    .assertError({ it.getMessage().equals(error.getMessage()) })
```